# .htaccess: Options not allowed here when access site via ip adress on CWP

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http-status-code-500

A site hosted on CWP Apache can be reached via server ip address with no need for any domain name, by providing ~username, e.g. URL:

```
http://100.0.0.1/~username/
```

instead of

```
http://www.websitename.com/
```

But as per title, when I try this way to access this website, CWP gives me 500 Internal Server Error with the followin alert in error log

```
"/home/username/public_html/.htaccess: Options not allowed here"
```

No error is given if I access the same site via domain name.

Seems like that the apache directives located in  the vhost websitename.com.conf file are affecting the folder only when the site is reached via domain name, but no when the site is reached via direct ip address.

As suggested by arkascha in the comment I have created a new domain with the ip address 100.0.0.1, and then I added the following apache lines to the file 100.0.0.1.conf

```
<Directory "/home/username/public_html">
    Options -Indexes -FollowSymLinks +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    AllowOverride All Options=ExecCGI,Includes,IncludesNOEXEC,Indexes,MultiViews,SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
</Directory>
```

The site folder path is stil the same of websitename.com (/home/username/public_html/), but after restarting Apache, nothing changed, same error again. What should I do in order to have Options usable in /public_html/.htaccess, when I visit the site via direct ip address access?

Comment: Well, both requests are processed by different virtual hosts. Those may well have different configurations.

Comment: Thank you arkascha for your hint, I edited the original question, I hope this time someone can lead me to the solution.

Comment: Do you need specialized vhosts at all? Why not use the fallback host (the default host) the exists and configure that? Unfortunately you cannot use a dotted IP address as a `ServerAlias` AFAIK, at least that was true some time ago, so it might be worth a check. What I do: I only have shells of vhost definitions, the only content is an `include` directive importing the actual configuration for that host. The advantage: you can share a single confirugation between several virtual hosts.

Comment: I don't need to have specialized vhost for each site, but this is what default come with CWP and I've sticked to it. BTW, I've already tried to set the same folder in the global default httpd.conf but the error remains. Too bad that my knowledge is so limited that I don't even know where to go for trying to find a solution for this problem. In any case, thank you again for every precious hint.

Comment: No, you miss understood what the default host is. There _always_ is a default host in the apache http server. It simply is _the first_ host that is configured. So that host is the one that processes requests that do _not_ carry a host header. So all requests to a naked ip address. Typically that one is stored in a file named such that it definitely comes _first_ and that makes clear that this is the default host. So there is absolutely no reason to modify the central configuration files with host specific stuff.

Comment: And "where to go" for trying to find a solution? The solution is to understand how the apache server actually works, is configured. Not to find some snippet you can copy from somewhere. Not sure if you read the documentation. The things I mentioned here are explained in there. As typical for OpenSource projects that documentation is of excellent quality and comes with great examples. Note: the actual documentation. Not some random tutorial you find on google.